# KeyError slug with like functionality

Tags: python, django-views

I am trying to create a like functionality. In my views.py :

```
@login_required
def like_post_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        post = Posts.objects.get(slug=kwargs['slug'])

        _, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(post=post,user=request.user)

        if not created:
            messages.warning(
                request,
                'You\'ve already liked the post.'
            )
    except Posts.DoesNotExist:
        messages.warning(
            request,
            'Post does not exist'
        )

    return HttpResponseRedirect(
        reverse_lazy(
            'posts:view',
            kwargs={'slug': kwargs['slug']}
        )
    )
# unlike posts
@login_required
def unlike_post_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        like = Like.objects.get(
            post__slug=kwargs['slug'],
            user=request.user
        )
    except Like.DoesNotExist:
        messages.warning(
            request,
            'You didn\'t like the post.'
        )
    else:
        like.delete()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(
        reverse_lazy(
            'posts:view',
            kwargs={'slug': kwargs['slug']}
        )
    )
```

EDIT: added relevant code from comments:

```
urlpatterns = [ 
   url(r'^$', views.index,name='index'), 
   url(r'^$', views.homepage,name='home'), 
   url(r'^profiles/$', views.profile,name='profiles'), 
   url(r'^profiles/post', views.posts,name='uploadpost'), 
   url(r'^profiles/edit', views.update_profile,name='editprofile'), 
   url(r'^profiles/like',views.like_post_view,name='posts'), 
   url(r'^profiles/unlike',views.unlike_post_view,name='posts')‌​, 
] if settings.DEBUG: 
      urlpatterns+= static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Please, provide your `urls.py` for your views.

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^$', views.homepage,name='home'),
    url(r'^profiles/$', views.profile,name='profiles'),
    url(r'^profiles/post', views.posts,name='uploadpost'),
    url(r'^profiles/edit', views.update_profile,name='editprofile'),
    url(r'^profiles/like',views.like_post_view,name='posts'),
    url(r'^profiles/unlike',views.unlike_post_view,name='posts'),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns+= static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: You should've put your patterns to original answer, but it's seen from code that there is no [captured parameters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#captured-parameters). I suggest you to pay attention to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views

Comment: @vishes_shell check comment above

Comment: Take a better look on my comment, i said that i it's better to be in original question rather than in comment. And i answered you that your urlpatterns lack of captured url parameters.:)

Comment: Thank you... Still new here. Editing the question was a hustle